# Ionic - CSS: cell background color from backend

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have to solve this problem: I want to display a list of rows with fixed height. Each row has to be horizontally divided in 2 equal parts. Each part has its background color, derived from the i-th element of the list they are referred. Each object in the list has 2 fields (named `leftColor` and `rightColor`) that contain the color to be displayed.

In pseudo-code:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let colorSource of sources">
    <ion-col col-6 background-color="{colorSource.leftColor}"> </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6 background-color="{colorSource.rightColor}"> </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Something like...

[image]

How could i obtain something like this?

TY in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `background-color="{colorSource.leftColor}"`, try to use `[ngStyle]="{'background-color': colorSource.leftColor}"`.

So your final code will be:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let colorSource of sources">
    <ion-col col-6 [ngStyle]="{'background-color': colorSource.leftColor}"> </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6 [ngStyle]="{'background-color': colorSource. rightColor}"> </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

For information about `ngStyle` diective please look [**here**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) official doc.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: TY, it's exactly what I'm looking for. I have another question (I edited the original question). Should I use a relative div element?

Comment: @AdrianoBellavita I am glad that it helped you. Please accept my answer. I have noticed from your profile that you have not accepted any answer in past. Please note that if someone answered to your question and that helped you, then accept that answer. For next requirement please don't edit this question instead create a separate question.

Comment: Alternatively, `[style.background-color]="colorSource.leftColor"`.

Comment: Please forgive me, I use stackoverflow very rarely. I just vote your answer as the right one, and I did the same for the oldest questions.
Regarding the second part of my question, as you recommend, I'll open a new thread.
TY.